# css media query responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I resize my browser I get the sidebar under the content and that looks fine but the text in p tags doesen't resize properly. Should I somehow target the p elements also? Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
    <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2016       
</div>
```

CSS

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 #menu {
    display: none;
 }

 #sidebar  {
    width: 100%;
}

 #content {
    width:100%;
}


}
```

Main CSS

```
    body {
    background-color: grey;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #27ae60;
}

#header h1 {
    background-color: #c0392b;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;

}

#content {

    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    float: left;
}

#sidebar {

    width: 360px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    float: right;
}

#footer {

    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;

}

p {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean? What is your expected behaviour? Please write lil more.

Comment: Why do you expect the font size of the paragraphs to change?

Comment: the sidebar and content fit in 480 px screen but the text inside them dont fit

Comment: you need to post your complete CSS code, not just the media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this rule in your main CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    [...]
}
```

The wrapper is 960 px wide. There is no rule for `#wrapper` in the media queries, so it will remain 960px wide on small screens. `#content` is 100% wide on small screens, so that's also 960px (since `#content` is inside `#wrapper`), And the same for the `<p>` tags inside `#content`: They will always be 100% = 960px wide.

The solution: Insert a rule for `#wrapper` for small screens(i.e. in your media queries), giving it also `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```